# Accessing Images on sub-domain odd behaviour

Tags: image, http, subdomain

I have a domain, lets call it domain.co.nz and I have 2 more subdomains setup as follows:

```
www.domain.co.nz
resources.domain.co.nz
management.domain.co.nz
```

So the server structure looks like this for each:

```
/management
/resources
/www
```

Now for some reason I can only access images under /resources/backgrounds
I cannot access images under /resources/icons

What could be the reason for this? Both folders are owned by the same user, under the same group, and are CHMOD exactly the same.

Any and all help greatly appreciated.

**EDIT AS PER REQUEST:**

This is how I would access them:

This works:

```
http://resources.domain.co.nz/backgrounds/icon_success.png' class='messageimg' />
```

However, this doesn't:

```
http://resources.domain.co.nz/icons/icon_success.png' class='messageimg' />
```

I can access my CSS sheet in the same was as the working one, but changing the folder to styles

Comment: Could you post some code to show how you access them.

Answer (score 0):

If I couldn't access images in one folder, I would:

- check the folder permissions (I see you've already done that)
- check the file permissions.
- Make sure the test image is some big, obvious image -- not something confusing like a screencapture of the "file not found" icon, or solid white, or solid black, or a 1 pixel x 1 pixel dot.
- Try to access the images directly: clear the cache of your web browser, then type `http://resources.domain.co.nz/backgrounds/icon_success.png` and `http://resources.domain.co.nz/icons/icon_success.png` directly into the address field of your web browsers. Perhaps they're actually *both* getting blocked, but I'm still seeing the remnants of one still lurking in my local web browser cache.
- test without any "class" or "name" or "id" attributes attached to the image, in a test ".html" file without including any PHP, CSS, or JavaScript. Perhaps some distant bit of CSS or JavaScript (jQuery?) is doing something weird.
- make sure the file actually exists in the folder I'm trying to fetch it from, and is spelled exactly the same as the requested filename. (I prefer all-lowercase filenames).
- Check for a .htaccess file in both directories -- perhaps the .htaccess file in the "working" directory allows access in a way that overrides some block-by-default; or perhaps the .htaccess file in the "not-working" directory blocks allow-by-default.
  ( [Apache .htaccess documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html) recommends not using any .htaccess files if possible).
- Check the web server's global configuration file (usually called [httpd.conf](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/configuring.html) ) for some setting that allows or blocks one directory differently than the other.
- Check the web server's global configuration file for a rewrite rule gone haywire. Perhaps one folder is getting redirected with a HTTP 302 redirect (or other 3xx redirect), and the other folder is being served directly with a httpd rewrite rule, and some browsers (for no good reason) treat them differently. (I've seen this happen with some smartphone browsers).
- Are you sure you're looking at the *real* httpd.conf file actually used by whatever server handles the URL that points at those images, and not some other httpd.conf file in some other folder ignored by that httpd server? I've only made that mistake twice this week. So far. :-).
- I hear that *some* web browsers, when viewing a page fetched with "`https://`" (TLS), refuse to show images from any "`http://`" source (even from exactly the same host name), but they *will* show images from a "`https://`" (TLS) source (sometimes even from a different machine).
- Ask the nice people at StackOverflow (or perhaps webmasters.stackexchange.com or some other hopefully-appropriate site). (I see you've already done that).